# Stripe Payout to a connected user's bank account using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm using stripe connect in my laravel app where merchant account are connected to app's stripe account (Main account) .

Currently i'm using Transfer method from stripe connect to transfer amount from main account to Merchant's stripe account.

```
    public function payout(Request $request)
    {

        try {
            $data = $request->all();
            $merchant = Merchant::find($data['merchant_id']);

            Transfer::create([ //s 2 s
                  'amount' => 1 * 100,
                  'currency' => 'eur',
                  'destination' => $merchant->asStripeAccount()?->id,
                  'description' => 'Stripe to stripe transfer',
              ]);

            return $this->sendSuccess('success');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            \Log::info($e->getMessage());
            return response()->json(['msg' => $e->getMessage()]);
        }

    }
```

There is a new requirement, that  app should send funds from main account to merchant's bank account. Since transfer from Main account -> Merchant stripe -> Merchant bank account takes few days.

```
        Payout::create([
                'amount' => 100,
                'currency' => 'eur',
                'method' => 'standard',
                'description' => 'payout to merchant',
            ],
            ['stripe_account' => $merchant->asStripeAccount()?->id]
        );
```

I tried the above method that is given in [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/manual-payouts).

With the above code i get the following message as it uses card by default as source_type:

```
{
    "msg": "You have insufficient funds in your Stripe account for this transfer. Your card balance is too low.  You can use the /v1/balance endpoint to view your Stripe balance (for more details, see stripe.com/docs/api#balance)."
}
```

When i hit the balance reterive api in stripe i get the following response:

```
{
    "object": "balance",
    "available": [
        {
            "amount": 6974202,
            "currency": "eur",
            "sourceTypes": {
                "card": 6974202
            }
        }
    ],
    "connectReserved": [
        {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "eur"
        }
    ],
    "livemode": false,
    "pending": [
        {
            "amount": -2135283,
            "currency": "eur",
            "sourceTypes": {
                "card": -2135283
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Stripe documentation also mentions that:

> The Payouts API is only for moving funds from a connected Stripe
> account’s balance into their external account.

Is it possible to  transfer funds from main account to merchant's bank account directly ?

Comment: Is the balance retrieval request also done when passing the `Stripe-Account` header? Or is that the JSON response shared the balance of the platform?

Comment: i used this route to retrieve balance:  `Route::get('/api/balance', function() {Stripe::setApiKey(config('fundis.stripeSecret'));
    return Balance::retrieve([]);}); ` Same response is returned from stripe cli in docs

Comment: That API request will retrieve the balance of the platform. You're trying to create a payout from the connected account, so you need to check there is sufficient balance on that account. Pass the `Stripe-Account` header there, too.

Comment: Yes I understand , this is only measure to check if balance is sufficient or not. But my issue is i am unable to perform payout although there is balance in my stripe account (main account).

Comment: The balance on your 'main' (platform) account is irrelevant here. You're creating the payout on the connected account so the funds will pull from the balance on the connected account.

Comment: Ah ok. I want to make payout from my 'main' (platform) to merchant's bank account. Is it possible ?

Comment: No. Payouts use the balance from the account they're created on. You need to transfer balance form the platform account to the relevant nonnected account first.